# Error connecting MySQL with Perl

Tags: mysql, windows, perl, cgi, dbi

I want to connect MySQL with Perl by using DBI.
The problem is whenever I try to connect to MySQL by using CGI this error will come out :

```html
Software error:
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load 'C:/xampp/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:%1 is not a valid Win32 application at C:/xampp/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at (eval 6) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at C:/xampp/htdocs/samples/insert1.cgi line 16.
```

This is the code that I have :

```js
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;
#include libraries
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 
## mysql user database name
my $db ="mysql";
## mysql database user name
my $user = "root";
 
## mysql database password
my $pass = "";
 
## user hostname : This should be "localhost" but it can be diffrent too
my $host="localhost";
 
## SQL query
my $query = "show tables";
 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);

 my $sqlQuery  = $dbh->prepare($query)
 or die "Can't prepare $query: $dbh->errstr\n";
 
my $rc = $sqlQuery->execute
or die "can't execute the query: $sqlQuery->errstr";
 #start the HTML
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";

print "<HTML>";
print "<HEAD>";
print "<TITLE>GeneMIS</TITLE>";
print "</HEAD>";
print "<BODY bgcolor=white>";
print "<h3>********** My Perl DBI Test ***************</h3>";
print "<p>Here is a list of tables in the MySQL database $db.</p>";
while (my @row= $sqlQuery->fetchrow_array()) {
my $tables = $row[0];
print "$tables\n<br>";
}
 
my $rc = $sqlQuery->finish;


#end the HTML
print "</BODY></HTML>";
exit(0);
```

My DBI is working just fine and I have mysql.dll in the folder already.
I already included the path in Environment Variables but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this error.
first i deleted the **perl folder** in **xampp folder** and i copied the **perl folder** in **strawberry folder** to the **xampp folder**

**delete** the perl folder in **C:\xampp\perl**

then go to 
**C:\strawberry and copy the perl folder to C:\xampp**

then restart xampp and run the program again.